# Would you teach the use of testMethod or @IsTest on test methods going forward

Tags: discussion

I was having a [discussion](https://twitter.com/SNUGSFBay/status/854524345191776256) on the usage of the `testMethod` modifier versus the `@IsTest` annotation. I have my opinion, but I'll try not to bias the results one way or another by expressing it here.

**If you were introducing someone to Apex, which would you use and why?**

I started a twitter poll as it seemed like an easier way to gather the results.
https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/854517221065752576

Comment: `testMethod` - cleaner and easier to read IMHO. Not sure it really matters though so it comes down to preference?

Comment: I like to use `@IsTest` because I think that when we read annotations, we understand faster that this is not code. Also, when I was using the `testMethod` modifier, I never knew where I had to add it. Because its surrounded by other method modifiers.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I'd go with `@isTest` based on [Jason Clark's answer in 2014 on your question from 2012](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25339/24889).

From that answer:

> Why? If I need to disable a test, I can just comment out the @isTest line like so:
>
> ```
> //@isTest
> static void TestSomething() { ... }
> ```

Beyond that, the `testMethod` modifier appears to be a one-off feature of Apex. By that, I mean that other programming features specific to Apex tend not to use keywords baked into the class definition or method signature.

The only other example of a class/method modifier that I can think of is `webservice`. Nearly everything else uses annotations. I think I'd prefer using `@isTest` for test methods just for sake of being consistent.

Comment: Never thought about this.....Good reason to use the annotation...